# Handling two Maps with multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to achieve following:

1. I have two Maps (not sure yet which safe to use and works properly)
2. Both are like `Map<Integer, Object>` (let's say from now `Map1` and `Map2`
3. `Object` is always inserted to `Map1` first
4. The `Integer` value is incremented with `AtomicInteger` every time `Object` is inserted to `Map1`
5. After insertion I need to get the first inserted `Object` from the `Map1` and move it to `Map2` and then perform asynchronous operation with the `Object`
6. In the callback of that operation I need to remove the `Object` from `Map2` and repeat

`Map1` is sort of a queue and `Map2` contains all running operations. The amount of running operations can be adjusted to be more than 1 at a time.

For example I execute 5 operations in a row and max amount for running operations is 4, the sequence would be:

Put all 5 into `Map1` with 0,1,2,3,4 ids. Then indexes 0,1,2,3 should be removed and moved to `Map2`. When first `Object` from `Map2` is ready, it should be removed and the last from `Map1` moved to `Map2`.

I tried with `ConcurrentHashMap` but iterating it with `Iterator.next()` started from the last inserted item and had some problems removing item from `Map2` when the object got ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map1 is sort of a queue`

Use a Blocking Queue which is a FIFO data structure.

Comment: What if I need to remove Object from the queue with id (Integer)? Kind of canceling before it's executed.

Comment: Those Queues doesn't seem to have any key for their values.

Comment: @Niko assuming you know which object to remove, you can use `remove(object)` method

Comment: I will do some refactoring and maybe I can get rid of the another Map and only use Queue, I will let you know the results tomorrow if Queue fits my needs.